# Need help on parsing JSON data from this API in a React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get Bitcoin Price from Coindesk API. This is my app:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

let bpiURL = 'http://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(bpiURL)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res);
                return res;
            })
            .then(response => this.setState({ data: response }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    {this.state.data.disclaimer}
                </p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that it works with `this.state.data.disclaimer` and `this.state.data.chartName` but it doesn't work with `this.state.data.bpi.USD.rate` which is what I need. How can I get that value?

EDIT: this is what I get from `this.state.data` :

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in p (at index.js:42) in div (at index.js:37) in App (at index.js:49)

Comment: Can you post the output of this.state.data ?

Comment: @LegenJerry Updated the question with this.state.data

Comment: @Ehsan You could `console.log(this.state.data)` instead of returning it in `render` for debugging purposes.

Comment: Sorry about that. formatting the output shows it does have `rate` property under USD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state.data.bpi.USD.rate` works, but only once the request has completed. Before that `this.state.data.bpi` will give `undefined`, and trying to access `USD` on that will give rise to an error.

You could change your default `data` to `null`, and check if `data` is set before you use it in the render method.

**Example**

```js
let bpiURL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(bpiURL)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => this.setState({ data: response }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.state.data && this.state.data.bpi.USD.rate}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';


const bpiURL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";

class App extends Component {
    // you should check component life cycle to prevent updating from fetch when component is unmounted
    _isMounted = false;
    state = {
        data: null,
        error: null

    };

    componentDidMount() {

        this._isMounted = true;
        fetch(bpiURL)
            .then(response => response.json())

            .then(response => this._isMounted && this.setState({data: response}))
            // introduce an error catch
            .catch(error => this._isMounted && this.setState({error}))
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }


    render() {
        const {data, error} = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="App">
                {/* optional : you could show the error message */}
                <p> {`USD rate :  ${ (data && data.bpi.USD.rate) || error }`}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Maybe it is also recommended to use a library like 'axios'  instead of native fetch